# (ID/ParentID) list to Hierarchical list

Tags: c#, list, linq-to-objects, hierarchical-data

`MyClass` consists of `ID` `ParentID` and `List<MyClass>` as `Children`

I have list of `MyClass` like this

```
ID  ParentID
1   0
2   7
3   1
4   5
5   1
6   2
7   1
8   6
9   0
10  9
```

Output (Hierarchical list) as `List<MyClass>`

```
1 __ 3
 |__ 5__ 4
 |__ 7__ 2__ 6__ 8
     |__ 11

9 __10
```

What is the simplest way to achieve this in linq?
P.S.: `ParentID` not sorted

**Edit:

My try:**

```
class MyClass
{
    public int ID;
    public int ParentID;
    public List<MyClass> Children = new List<MyClass>();
    public MyClass(int id, int parent_id)
    {
        ID = id;
        ParentID = parent_id;
    }
}
```

initialize sample data and try to reach hierarchical data

```
 List<MyClass> items = new List<MyClass>()
{
    new MyClass(1, 0), 
    new MyClass(2, 7), 
    new MyClass(3, 1), 
    new MyClass(4, 5), 
    new MyClass(5, 1), 
    new MyClass(6, 2), 
    new MyClass(7,1), 
    new MyClass(8, 6), 
    new MyClass(9, 0), 
    new MyClass(10, 9), 
    new MyClass(11, 7), 
};

Dictionary<int, MyClass> dic = items.ToDictionary(ee => ee.ID);

foreach (var c in items)
    if (dic.ContainsKey(c.ParentID))
        dic[c.ParentID].Children.Add(c);
```

as you can see, lots of items I don't want still in the dictionary

Comment: What type of data structure should the output be in?

Comment: @Jon: Please refer to my updated question

Comment: But a `List` is not a hierarchical data structure. To put it differently, how do you propose to turn a `List` into the pictured tree?

Comment: @jon: Please refer to my updated question, i can turn the data back to list by simple foreach statement

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question right. What do you want your output as?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For hierarchical data, you need recursion - a foreach loop won't suffice.

```
Action<MyClass> SetChildren = null;
SetChildren = parent =>
    {
        parent.Children = items
            .Where(childItem => childItem.ParentID == parent.ID)
            .ToList();

        //Recursively call the SetChildren method for each child.
        parent.Children
            .ForEach(SetChildren);
    };

//Initialize the hierarchical list to root level items
List<MyClass> hierarchicalItems = items
    .Where(rootItem => rootItem.ParentID == 0)
    .ToList();

//Call the SetChildren method to set the children on each root level item.
hierarchicalItems.ForEach(SetChildren);
```

`items` is the same list you use. Notice how the `SetChildren` method is called within itself. This is what constructs the hierarchy.

Comment: This is less performant than the OPs original code. The dictionary method is far superior.

Comment: @user347805 @RamiShareef I want the output list add like print `|__|__11` if that is a child. and if that is a parent just print `1`. help please. thank

Comment: @sarin it ends up in infinite loop . what's the break condition

Answer (score 46):

Recursion is not necessary here if you build the parent-child relationships before filtering. Since the members of the list remain the same objects, as long as you associate each member of the list with its immediate children, all of the necessary relationships will be built.

This can be done in two lines:

```
items.ForEach(item => item.Children = items.Where(child => child.ParentID == item.ID)
                                           .ToList());
List<MyClass> topItems = items.Where(item => item.ParentID == 0).ToList();
```

Comment: I did not think of that. You're correct. Creating the hierarchy does not require recursion, only **traversing** does.

Comment: Traversing does not too. :)

Comment: Just used this for a similar project. Beautiful solution and efficient too.

Answer (score 1):

I have required such functionality and compare both methods and find method 2nd is faster than 1st :), right now in my database cards or records are limited but 1st method taking 4 times more time to complete.

may be this can help for those who are conscious about time.

1 method

---

```
    public JsonResult CardData()
    {
        var watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
        OrgChartWithApiContext db = new OrgChartWithApiContext();

        var items = db.Cards.ToList();
        Action<Card> SetChildren = null;
        SetChildren = parent => {
            parent.Children = items
                .Where(childItem => childItem.ParentId == parent.id)
                .ToList();

            //Recursively call the SetChildren method for each child.
            parent.Children
                .ForEach(SetChildren);
        };

        //Initialize the hierarchical list to root level items
        List<Card> hierarchicalItems = items
            .Where(rootItem => !rootItem.ParentId.HasValue)
            .ToList();

        //Call the SetChildren method to set the children on each root level item.
        hierarchicalItems.ForEach(SetChildren);
        watch.Stop();
        var timetaken = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;

        return new JsonResult() { Data = hierarchicalItems, ContentType = "Json", JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
    }
```

---

method 2

---

```
    public JsonResult Card2Data()
    {
        var watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
        OrgChartWithApiContext db = new OrgChartWithApiContext();
        var items = db.Cards.ToList();
        List<Card> topItems = items.Where(item => !item.ParentId.HasValue).ToList();
        topItems.ForEach(item => item.Children = items.Where(child => child.ParentId == item.id).ToList());
        watch.Stop();
        var timetaken = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        return new JsonResult() { Data = topItems, ContentType = "Json", JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who are looking for a more generic approach that is very quick and easy to use. I have made some generic interfaces and extension methods that will quickly sort and return hierarchical data.

```
public interface IHierarchicalData<TData>
{
    public IHierarchicalData<TData>? Parent { get; set; }
    public IList<IHierarchicalData<TData>> Children { get; set; }
    public TData? Data { get; set; }
}

public class DefaultHierarchy<TData> : IHierarchicalData<TData>
{
    public IHierarchicalData<TData>? Parent { get; set; }
    public IList<IHierarchicalData<TData>> Children { get; set; } = new List<IHierarchicalData<TData>>();
    public TData? Data { get; set; }        
}

public static class HierarchyExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<THierarchyModel> CreateHierarchy<THierarchyModel, TData, TId>(this IEnumerable<TData> flatList, Func<TData, TId> idSelector, Func<TData, TId?> parentIdSelector)
        where THierarchyModel : IHierarchicalData<TData>, new()
    {
        var lookup = flatList.Select(f => new THierarchyModel { Data = f })
                                                       .Where(item => item.Data is not null)
                                                       .ToDictionary(h => idSelector(h.Data));

        foreach (var item in lookup.Values)
        {
            var parentId = parentIdSelector(item.Data);
            if (parentId is null || !lookup.TryGetValue(parentId, out var parent))
            {
                yield return item;
                continue;
            }

            parent.Children.Add(item);
            item.Parent = parent;
        }
    }

    public static IEnumerable<IHierarchicalData<TData>> CreateHierarchy<TData, TId>(this IEnumerable<TData> flatList, Func<TData, TId> idSelector, Func<TData, TId?> parentIdSelector)
    {
        return flatList.CreateHierarchy<DefaultHierarchy<TData>,TData, TId>(idSelector, parentIdSelector);
    }
}
```

Usage is very simple. All you have to do is pass in the func to get the parentId and Id of the item. Then you can traverse the hierarchy and get the information you need by accessing the "Data" property.

```
private IEnumerable<IHierarchicalData<TestHierarchy>> hierarchyData 
     => testHierarchy.CreateHierarchy(t => t.Id, t => t.ParentId);

private class TestHierarchy
{
    public int Id { get; set; }     
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

private List<TestHierarchy> testHierarchy = new()
    {
        new() { Id = 1, ParentId = null, Name = "Top Level 1" },
            new() { Id = 2, ParentId = 1, Name = "Top Level 1.1" },
            new() { Id = 3, ParentId = 1, Name = "Top Level 1.2" },
                new() { Id = 12, ParentId = 3, Name = "Top Level 1.2.1" },
            new() { Id = 10, ParentId = 1, Name = "Top Level 1.3" },
            new() { Id = 11, ParentId = 1, Name = "Top Level 1.4" },
        new() { Id = 4, ParentId = null, Name = "Top Level 2" },
            new() { Id = 5, ParentId = 4, Name = "Top Level 2.1" },
            new() { Id = 6, ParentId = 4, Name = "Top Level 2.2" },
            new() { Id = 7, ParentId = 4, Name = "Top Level 2.3" },
                new() { Id = 13, ParentId = 7, Name = "Top Level 2.3.1" },
                    new() { Id = 14, ParentId = 13, Name = "Top Level 2.3.1.1" },
            new() { Id = 8, ParentId = 4, Name = "Top Level 2.4" },
        new() { Id = 9, ParentId = null, Name = "Top Level 3" },
    };
```

[image: Image of the above code]