# c# build hierarchy in reverse

Tags: c#, linq, hierarchy

I have two methods to return a dynamic hierarchical structure from a flat List.  The first works great using the recursive method here: [(ID/ParentID) list to Hierarchical list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9409021/id-parentid-list-to-hierarchical-list).

I'm now trying to do the same thing except this time show only those categories and reports which have a saved report output.  I'm not sure where to start as everything I find is building from root down and I need to go from the bottom up.

I get something like this now in my first method:

```
Category 1
  |_Sub Category 1
    |_Report 1
    |_Report 2
      |_Saved Output
Category 2
  |_Sub Category 2
  | |_Report 3
  | |_Report 4
  |_Sub Category 3
    |_Report 5
    |_Report 6
      |_Saved Output
Category 3
  |_Sub Category 4
    |_Report 7
```

What I want in my second method is this:

```
Category 1
  |_Sub Category 1
    |_Report 2
      |_Saved Output
Category 2
  |_Sub Category 3
    |_Report 6
      |_Saved Output
```

Here's my basic test structure:

```
class Flat
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int parentId { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public bool isOutput { get; set; }

    public Flat(int i, int pid, string n, bool o)
    {
        this.id = i;
        this.parentId = pid;
        this.name = n;
        this.isOutput = o;
    }
}

class MyClass
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int parentId { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public bool isOutput { get; set; }

    public List<MyClass> children { get; set; }

    public MyClass()
    {
        this.children = new List<MyClass>();
    }
}

List<Flat> items = new List<Flat>()
        {
                new Flat(1,0,"Category 1",false),
                new Flat(4,1,"Sub Category 1",false),
                new Flat(8,4,"Report 1",false),
                new Flat(9,4,"Report 2",false),
                new Flat(15,9,"Saved Output",true),
                new Flat(2,0,"Category 2",false),
                new Flat(5,2,"Sub Category 2",false),
                new Flat(10,5,"Report 3",false),
                new Flat(11,5,"Report 4",false),
                new Flat(6,2,"Sub Category 3",false),
                new Flat(12,6,"Report 5",false),
                new Flat(13,6,"Report 6",false),
                new Flat(16,13,"Saved Output",true),
                new Flat(3,0,"Category 3",false),
                new Flat(7,3,"Sub Category 4",false),
                new Flat(14,7,"Report 7",false)
        };
```

Comment: Well, if you're not super worried about efficiency, just build the whole tree and then remove the elements that don't belong once you're done.  Unless the sections to be removed are *huge* that shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Is the hierarchy only for visualization? In which case @mellamokb has the approach below. If you need to get the structure as well, you can extend it to be a Tree instead of List.

Comment: FYI the accepted answer in that question you linked to was much more complicated than it needed to be. The exact same result can be accomplished more efficiently with 2 short lines of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To build from the bottom up, you need to start with all the leaf nodes that are valid (`output == true`), and then work upwards through all parent nodes until you reach the root.  Here's one method that should work:

```
List<Flat> GetSavedOutput(List<Flat> items)
{
    // get all output leaf nodes
    var toAdd = items.Where (i => i.isOutput == true).ToList();
    var result = new List<Flat>();

    // grab all parent nodes that are not already included until
    // there's nothing new to add
    while (toAdd.Count > 0)
    {
        result.AddRange(toAdd);
        toAdd = items.Where (i => !result.Contains(i)
                               && result.Any (r => r.parentId == i.id)).ToList();
    }

    return result;
}
```

This is short and quick, and should work well for small, simple trees, but it is not the most efficient method because of processing the same nodes over and over again.  A slightly more complex, but better method, would be to walk up the parent tree for each item:

```
List<Flat> GetSavedOutput(List<Flat> items)
{
    var savedOutput = items.Where (i => i.isOutput == true).ToList();
    var result = new List<Flat>();

    foreach (var item in savedOutput) {
        result.Add(item);
        var temp = item;
        do {
            temp = items.Single (i => i.id == temp.parentId);
            result.Add(temp);
        } while (temp.parentId != 0);
    }

    return result;
}
```

If this is still not efficient enough, you can get a little more performance by storing references to the parent node in each `Flat` instance, so that the parent can be directly referenced in `O(1)` without having to look it up using a call to `Single`, which has efficiency `O(n)`.

Answer (score 1):

First I would suggest defining a recursive method to determine whether an item has a path to an output item, based on a given list:

```
static bool HasPathToOutput(List<Flat> items, Flat item)
{
    if (item.isOutput)
    {
        return true;
    }

    // Recursively determine whether any of the item's children have
    // a path to an output
    return items.Where(i => i.parentId == item.id).Any(i => HasPathToOutput(items, i));
}
```

Then use that method to run your list through some LINQ queries, first getting the items that have a path to a saved output, then building the hierarchy, and finally, retrieving just the items that are at the top of their hierarchy:

```
// Generate a predicate based on the list
List<MyClass> foundItems = 
       items.Where(item => HasPathToOutput(items, item))
            .Select(f => new MyClass { id = f.id, isOutput = f.isOutput, parentId = f.parentId, name = f.name })
            .ToList();

// Generate child relationships
foundItems.ForEach(item => item.children = foundItems.Where(child => child.parentId == item.id).ToList());

// Filter out top-level items
List<MyClass> topLevel = foundItems.Where(i => i.parentId == 0).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to traverse your data [depth-first order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal)

This will look at all your leaf nodes first, add saved elements to the list and signal to the parent nodes that the root node was saved.

```
public bool StoreSavedElements(List<Tree> elements)
{
    bool nodeSaved = false;

    foreach (Tree child in childs)
    {
        if (child.StoreSavedElements(elements))
        {
            nodeSaved = true;
        }
    }

    if (this.text == "Saved")
    {
        nodeSaved = true;
        elements.Add(this);
    }

    return nodeSaved;
}
```