# Can I have a TreeListView with the indeterminate setting asserted programmatically only (and denied to the user)?

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox, objectlistview, treelistview

I'm using Phillip Piper's `ObjectListView` wrapper, specifically, a `TreeListView`

My `TreeListView`:

- Checkboxes: True
- CheckedAspectName: {name of bool? property in my
  model)
- HierarchicalCheckboxes: True
- TriStateCheckboxes: true
- View: Details

I set `TriStateCheckboxes` to True because I want my `TreeListView` to be able to display the `indeterminate` symbol in the `TreeListView’s` checkboxes. However, I don't want the user to ever be able to explicitly set a checkbox to an `indeterminate` value. Rather, when a user clicks on a checkbox, I want it to toggle only between checked and unchecked. If a branch checkbox and all its children’s checkboxes are checked, and the children's checkboxes transition to a mix of checked and unchecked, I want the branch’s checkbox to show the `indeterminate` symbol.

In other words, the indeterminate state is ever only to be asserted programmatically and then only on a branch when the checkboxes of the branch’s children are not solely all checked or not solely all unchecked.

Realizing that a tristate checkbox cycles: checked, indeterminate, unchecked, I tried forcing an indeterminate state to an unchecked state when the user clicks on a checked checkbox, but that didn’t work, i.e., the checkbox state in the TreeListView remains unchanged after executing my ObjTreeListViewPreview_ItemChecked code.

**Note: the class ClsTreeListViewPreview derives from TreeListView**

```
private void ObjTreeListViewPreview_ItemChecked(object sender, ItemCheckedEventArgs e)
{

    ClsTreeListViewPreview objTreeListViewPreview = (ClsTreeListViewPreview)sender;

    if (objTreeListViewPreview.MouseMoveHitTest.Item.CheckState == CheckState.Indeterminate)
    {
        objTreeListViewPreview.MouseMoveHitTest.Item.CheckState = CheckState.Unchecked;
    }

}
```

Is what I want possible with a `TreeListView` that has `tristate` and `hierarchical` checkboxes ? If so, which delegates and methods are necessary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a Winforms `TreeListView` with `tristate checkboxes` working where the `indeterminate` setting is denied to the user. The `indeterminate` setting appears in a checkbox only when the user sets the checkbox's child objects to a mix of checked and unchecked.

`HierarchicalCheckboxes` are not used. All checkbox settings are managed manually.

It uses a CheckStatePutter, an ItemChecked event handler, and a HeaderCheckBoxChanging event handler (when a header checkbox is used) to manually manage checkbox settings

**Demo code follows**

Code is self-contained (except for the `ObjectListView.dll`). Create a Winforms project with an empty form and copy/paste the two classes below

**Main form**

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace NovaSysEng
{
    public partial class ClsFormMain : Form
    {
        public ClsFormMain()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            ClsTriStateTreeListView objFooTree = new ClsTriStateTreeListView(showHeaderCheckBox: true)
            {
                Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0),
                Dock = DockStyle.Fill
            };

            // The model supports the creation of a tree hierarchy whose depth is not known until run time.
            // Each item requires an id and a parentId just like in a DataTreeListView.
            // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9409021/id-parentid-list-to-hierarchical-list

            objFooTree.AddItem(id: 1, parentId: 0, name: "A", isChecked: false, foo: "foo A");
            objFooTree.AddItem(id: 2, parentId: 1, name: "A.1", isChecked: false, foo: "foo A.1");
            objFooTree.AddItem(id: 3, parentId: 1, name: "A.2", isChecked: false, foo: "foo A.2");
            objFooTree.AddItem(id: 4, parentId: 1, name: "A.3", isChecked: false, foo: "foo A.3");
            objFooTree.AddItem(id: 5, parentId: 0, name: "B", isChecked: false, foo: "foo B");
            objFooTree.AddItem(id: 6, parentId: 5, name: "B.1", isChecked: false, foo: "foo B.1");
            objFooTree.AddItem(id: 7, parentId: 5, name: "B.2", isChecked: false, foo: "foo B.2");
            objFooTree.AddItem(id: 8, parentId: 5, name: "B.3", isChecked: false, foo: "foo B.3");
            objFooTree.AddItem(id: 9, parentId: 8, name: "B.3.1", isChecked: false, foo: "foo B.3.1");

            SuspendLayout();
            Controls.Add(objFooTree);
            objFooTree.Load();
            objFooTree.ExpandAll();
            objFooTree.AutoResizeColumns();
            ResumeLayout();
        }
    }
}
```

**Class ClsTriStateTreeListView**

```
using BrightIdeasSoftware;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace NovaSysEng
{
    class ClsTriStateTreeListView : BrightIdeasSoftware.TreeListView
    {
        private readonly bool showHeaderCheckBox = false;

        private List<ClsItem> itemList;
        readonly OLVColumn olvColumnName;
        readonly OLVColumn olvColumnFoo;

        /// <summary>
        /// CTOR
        /// </summary>
        public ClsTriStateTreeListView() : this(false)
        {
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// CTOR
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="showHeaderCheckBox"></param>
        public ClsTriStateTreeListView(bool showHeaderCheckBox) : base()
        {
            this.showHeaderCheckBox = showHeaderCheckBox;

            CheckBoxes = true;
            View = View.Details;
            UseAlternatingBackColors = true;
            MultiSelect = false;
            CheckedAspectName = "";
            GridLines = true;
            OwnerDraw = true;
            ShowGroups = false;
            TriStateCheckBoxes = true;
            VirtualMode = true;
            HierarchicalCheckboxes = false;

            ItemChecked += FooTreeListView_ItemChecked;
            HeaderCheckBoxChanging += ClsFooTreeListView_HeaderCheckBoxChanging;

            itemList = new List<ClsItem>();

            olvColumnName = new BrightIdeasSoftware.OLVColumn
            {
                AspectName = "Name",
                Text = "Name",
                HeaderCheckBoxUpdatesRowCheckBoxes = false
            };

            AllColumns.Add(olvColumnName);
            Columns.Add(olvColumnName);

            olvColumnFoo = new BrightIdeasSoftware.OLVColumn
            {
                AspectName = "Foo",
                Text = "Foo",
            };

            AllColumns.Add(olvColumnFoo);
            Columns.Add(olvColumnFoo);

            // Don't allow the user to put a checkbox in the indeterminate state.
            // When clicked, a checkbox cycles through 3 states in the order: checked, indeterminate, unchecked
            // So, if the checkbox state is Indeterminate, force it to unchecked.
            // An exception is when a checkbox has the Indeterminate setting and the model IgnoreIndeterminate
            // property is true. This is for the case when we want to set the checkbox to Indeterminate
            // programattically and have it stick.
            CheckStatePutter = delegate (Object rowObject, CheckState newValue)
            {
                if (newValue == CheckState.Indeterminate && ((ClsItem)rowObject).IgnoreIndeterminate)
                {
                    return CheckState.Indeterminate;
                }
                else if (newValue == CheckState.Indeterminate)
                {
                    return CheckState.Unchecked;
                }
                else
                {
                    return newValue;
                }
            };

            CanExpandGetter = delegate (Object x)
            {
                return ((ClsItem)x).Children.Count > 0;
            };

            ChildrenGetter = delegate (Object x)
            {
                return ((ClsItem)x).Children;
            };
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// If the user clicks on the HeaderCheckBox, set all descendants accordingly
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        private void ClsFooTreeListView_HeaderCheckBoxChanging(object sender, HeaderCheckBoxChangingEventArgs e)
        {
            ItemChecked -= FooTreeListView_ItemChecked;

            foreach (ClsItem topLevelItem in this.Objects)
            {
                if (e.NewCheckState == CheckState.Checked)
                {
                    CheckObject(topLevelItem);
                    CheckDescendantCheckboxes(topLevelItem);
                }
                else
                {
                    UncheckObject(topLevelItem);
                    UncheckDescendantCheckboxes(topLevelItem);
                }
            }

            ItemChecked += FooTreeListView_ItemChecked;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Set the model IgnoreIndeterminate property to true then set the checkbox to Indeterminate
        /// using the CheckIndeterminateObject method. CheckStatePutter will be invoked and the 
        /// Indeterminate setting will be ignored for this particular case. Finally, set the model
        /// IgnoreIndeterminate property to false so an Indeterminate checkbox setting will otherwise
        /// be change to an Unchecked setting.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="rowObject"></param>
        public override void CheckIndeterminateObject(object rowObject)
        {
            ((ClsItem)rowObject).IgnoreIndeterminate = true;
            base.CheckIndeterminateObject(rowObject);
            ((ClsItem)rowObject).IgnoreIndeterminate = false;
        }

        private void UncheckDescendantCheckboxes(ClsItem objTreeItemModel)
        {
            foreach (ClsItem child in GetChildren(objTreeItemModel))
            {
                UncheckObject(child);
                UncheckDescendantCheckboxes(child);
            }
        }
        private void CheckDescendantCheckboxes(ClsItem objTreeItemModel)
        {
            foreach (ClsItem child in GetChildren(objTreeItemModel))
            {
                CheckObject(child);
                CheckDescendantCheckboxes(child);
            }
        }

        private void FooTreeListView_ItemChecked(object sender, ItemCheckedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("In FooTreeListView_ItemChecked");

            ItemChecked -= FooTreeListView_ItemChecked;

            ClsItem objTreeItemModel = (ClsItem)((OLVListItem)e.Item).RowObject;

            //set descendant checkboxes
            if (IsChecked(objTreeItemModel))
            {
                CheckDescendantCheckboxes(objTreeItemModel);
            }
            else
            {
                UncheckDescendantCheckboxes(objTreeItemModel);
            }

            ClsItem objTreeItemModelParent = (ClsItem)GetParent(objTreeItemModel);

            //Set ancestor checkboxes 
            while (objTreeItemModelParent != null)
            {
                bool allChildrenChecked = true;
                bool allChildrenUnchecked = true;

                // If all 1st generation children of the parent are checked, set parent to checked
                // If all 1st generation children of the parent are unchecked, set parent to unchecked
                // Otherwise, set parent to indeterminte
                foreach (ClsItem child in GetChildren(objTreeItemModelParent))
                {
                    if (IsChecked(child))
                    {
                        allChildrenUnchecked = false;
                    }

                    if (!IsChecked(child))
                    {
                        allChildrenChecked = false;
                    }

                    if (IsCheckedIndeterminate(child))
                    {
                        allChildrenUnchecked = false;
                        allChildrenChecked = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (allChildrenChecked)
                {
                    CheckObject(objTreeItemModelParent);
                }
                else if (allChildrenUnchecked)
                {
                    UncheckObject(objTreeItemModelParent);
                }
                else
                {
                    CheckIndeterminateObject(objTreeItemModelParent);
                }

                objTreeItemModelParent = (ClsItem)GetParent(objTreeItemModelParent);

            } // while


            if (showHeaderCheckBox)
            {
                bool allChecked = true;
                bool allUnchecked = true;

                foreach (ClsItem topLevelItem in this.Objects)
                {
                    if (IsChecked(topLevelItem))
                    {
                        allUnchecked = false;
                    }

                    if (!IsChecked(topLevelItem))
                    {
                        allChecked = false;
                    }

                    if (IsCheckedIndeterminate(topLevelItem))
                    {
                        allUnchecked = false;
                        allChecked = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                HeaderCheckBoxChanging -= ClsFooTreeListView_HeaderCheckBoxChanging;

                if (allChecked)
                {
                    CheckHeaderCheckBox(olvColumnName);
                }
                else if (allUnchecked)
                {
                    UncheckHeaderCheckBox(olvColumnName);
                }
                else
                {
                    CheckIndeterminateHeaderCheckBox(olvColumnName);
                }

                HeaderCheckBoxChanging += ClsFooTreeListView_HeaderCheckBoxChanging;

            } // if (showHeaderCheckBox)

            ItemChecked += FooTreeListView_ItemChecked;

        } // private void FooTreeListView_ItemChecked(object sender, ItemCheckedEventArgs e)

        public void AddItem(int id, int parentId, string name, bool? isChecked, string foo)
        {
            itemList.Add(new ClsItem(id, parentId, name, isChecked, foo));
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// After using the AddItem method to add tree items, call this method to load the model into the TreeListView.
        /// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9409021/id-parentid-list-to-hierarchical-list
        /// </summary>
        public void Load()
        {
            itemList.ForEach(item => item.Children = itemList.Where(child => child.ParentId == item.Id).ToList());
            List<ClsItem> topItems = itemList.Where(item => item.ParentId == 0).ToList();
            ((OLVColumn)this.Columns[0]).HeaderCheckBox = this.showHeaderCheckBox;
            Roots = topItems;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This model supports the creation of a tree hierarchy whose depth is not known until run time
        /// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9409021/id-parentid-list-to-hierarchical-list
        /// </summary>
        private class ClsItem
        {
            int id;
            int parentId;
            string name;
            bool? isChecked;
            string foo;
            List<ClsItem> children = new List<ClsItem>();
            bool ignoreIndeterminate;

            public ClsItem(int id, int parentId, string name, bool? isChecked, string foo)
            {
                this.id = id;
                this.parentId = parentId;
                this.name = name;
                this.isChecked = isChecked;
                this.foo = foo;
            }

            public bool? IsChecked { get => isChecked; set => isChecked = value; }
            public string Name { get => name; set => name = value; }
            public string Foo { get => foo; set => foo = value; }
            public int Id { get => id; set => id = value; }
            public int ParentId { get => parentId; set => parentId = value; }
            public List<ClsItem> Children { get => children; set => children = value; }
            public bool IgnoreIndeterminate { get => ignoreIndeterminate; set => ignoreIndeterminate = value; }
        }
    }
}
```